# Recursive N-way merge/diff algorithm for directory trees?

Tags: java, algorithm, merge, tree, diff

What algorithms or Java libraries are available to do N-way, recursive diff/merge of directories?

I need to be able to generate a list of folder trees that have many identical files, and have subdirectories with many similar files.  I want to be able to use 2-way merge operations to quickly remove as much redundancy as possible.

### Goals:

- Find pairs of directories that have many similar files between them.
- Generate short list of directory pairs that can be synchronized with 2-way merge to eliminate duplicates
- Should operate recursively (there may be nested duplicates of higher-level directories)
- Run time and storage should be O(n log n) in numbers of directories and files
- Should be able to use an embedded DB or page to disk for processing more files than fit in memory (100,000+).
- Optional: generate an ancestry and change-set between folders
- Optional: sort the merge operations by how many duplicates they can elliminate

I know how to use hashes to find duplicate files in roughly O(n) space, but I'm at a loss for how to go from this to finding  partially overlapping sets between folders and their children.

**EDIT: some clarification**
The tricky part is the difference between "exact same" contents (otherwise hashing file hashes would work) and "similar" (which will not).  Basically, I want to feed this algorithm at a set of directories and have it return a set of 2-way merge operations I can perform in order to reduce duplicates as much as possible with as few conflicts possible.  It's effectively constructing an ancestry tree showing which folders are derived from each other.

The end goal is to let me incorporate a bunch of different folders into one common tree.  For example, I may have a folder holding programming projects, and then copy some of its contents to another computer to work on it.  Then I might back up and intermediate version to flash drive.  Except I may have 8 or 10 different versions, with slightly different organizational structures or folder names.  I need to be able to merge them one step at a time, so I can chose how to incorporate changes at each step of the way.

This is actually more or less what I intend to do with my utility (bring together a bunch of scattered backups from different points in time).  I figure if I can do it right I may as well release it as a small open source util.  I think the same tricks might be useful for comparing XML trees though.

Comment: define "many similar files."  You want to delete folders that have the exact same contents as another folder?  Or you want to simply delete duplicates throughout all folders?  If the former, look into hash-trees.  If the latter, I don't see what's wrong with using a hash-table for store the files.

Comment: Uh, not exactly either. Let me clarify: I want to find folders that have similar contents and similar subfolders as other ones. I have edited more info into the question. 

The problem with doing this manually is that at last count I had 300 THOUSAND plus files (in a partially organized form), 30 thousand subdirectories, and 400 GB of raw data.

Comment: I dunno, but the tool to *avoid* this situation would have been distributed version control (git, hg, etc.)

Comment: Reconstructing the ancestry is not possible when two copies have diverged (that is, each one contains changes the other lacks). The common ancestor is lost. I don't even see a way to determine whether this has happened, when two files are similar but a little different.

Comment: @Jason(1): Distributed version control is indeed one way to prevent the problem. The issue comes with large binary files (images, etc) where it is inefficient to have more than a HEAD copy.  In any case, the situation is what it is right now, and I can only try to prevent it in the future.
@Jason(2): I don't actually need to construct the *complete ancestry,* just create a set of pairs to merge which minimize the number of merges and conflicts while maximizing the number of duplicates removed.  Also, for these purposes I only care about identical files, not similar ones.

Comment: Also, note that on a desktop computer, a million filenames will fit in memory with no problems. So no external database should be needed.

Comment: @Jason: Not in Java, they won't: don't forget I need to store the path (which may be quite long), and that every character is 2 bytes, PLUS there's a sizable overhead for every object, and even bigger for each string.  IIRC, each string object has roughly 40 bytes of overhead, plus if you add in overhead for each entry in something like a HashMap... the upshot is that it's not really safe to work with more than a few hundred thousand file names at once in memory unless you remove redundant path prefixes somehow.

Comment: Just thought I'd add that I understand exactly what you are looking for, what problem you are trying to solve, and I would be thrilled to have a solution myself.  I've been thinking about this problem for some time and it would bring joy to my life if there was a nice solution out there.  Are you committed to java?  I'm working in node.js/javascript and may be building something along these lines.

Answer (score 2):

It seems desirable just to work on the filenames and sizes (and timestamps if you find that they are reliable), to avoid reading in all those files and hashing or diffing them.

Here's what comes to mind.

- Load all the data from the filesystem. It'll be big, but it'll fit in memory.
- Make a list of candidate directory-pairs with similarity scores. For each directory-name that appears in both trees, score 1 point for all pairs of directories that share that name. For each filename that appears in both trees (but not so often that it's meaningless), score 1 point for all pairs of directories that contain a file with that name. Score bonus points if the two files are identical. Score bonus points if the filename doesn't appear anywhere else. Each time you give points, also give some points to all ancestor-pairs, so that if a/x/y/foo.txt is similar to b/z/y/foo.txt, then the pairs `(a/x/y, b/z/y)` and `(a/x, b/z)` and `(a, b)` all get points.
- Optionally, discard all pairs with scores too low to bother with, and critically examine the other pairs. Up to now we've only considered ways that directories are similar. Look again, and penalize directory-pairs that show signs of *not* having common ancestry. (A general way to do this would be to calculate the maximum score the two directories could possibly have, if they both had all the files and they were all identical; and reject the pair if only a small fraction of that possible score was actually achieved. But it might be better to do something cheap and heuristic, or to skip this step entirely.)
- Choose the best-scoring candidate directory-pair. Output it. Eliminate those directories and all their subdirectories from contention. Repeat.

Choosing the right data structures is left as an exercise.

This algorithm makes no attempt to find similar files with different filenames. You can do that across large sets of files using something like the rsync algorithm, but I'm not sure you need it.

This algorithm makes no serious attempt to determine whether two files are actually similar. It just scores 1 point for the same filename and bonus points for the same size and timestamp. You certainly could diff them to assign a more precise score. I doubt it's worth it.